# Repo sync, fetches local credentials

Tags: git, ssh-keys, repo

I have done a repo init successfully but when I try to do repo sync I get permission denied. It tries to access the repo with my local credentials (i.e. windows login azure ID) and I do not know how to prevent this. The git configuration is set up with my remote credentials, as well as the .repo_giftconfig.json file, yet it still fetches my local username.

This is what it prints in my console:

```
AzureAD+XXXXXXX@DESKTOP-XXXXXXX MINGW64 /c/my_repo

$ repo sync

AzureAD+XXXXXXX@my_company.net: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Comment: What is ".repo_giftconfig.json" file ? And what is its content ?

Comment: Not sure what it is used for, but judging by the name it seems important. It contains:

{
 "user.name": [
    "mycompanyusername"
  ],
  "user.email": [
    "myemail@company.com"
  ],
  "push.default": [
    "simple"
  ]
}

Comment: What I mean is, where does it come from ? Auto generated ? Some documentation ? Did you find any reference to this file on the internet or in the repo documentation ? I never encounter such a file.